# Single column referencing 2 columns at the same time in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I saw several similar questions but never exactly what I'm trying to do.

So I have a plans table that have a plan id that has 2 columns as primary key (plan_id and frequency), for exemple:
id:1, frequency:1   (Plan 1, charged every month)
id:1, frequency:6   (Plan 1, charged every 6 months)
id:1, frequency:12   (Plan 1, charged every 12 months)
id:2, frequency:1   (Plan 2, charged every month)
...

Then in the table "website", every row would point to one of these plans. Is there a way to have only one column somehow pointing to a combination of the 2 columns from the plans table? The website table already has so many columns that I'm trying to avoid 2 more columns.

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT:**
I thought about having a different plan_id for every different version of the plan, but they need to be all related, so plan 1 with frequency 1,6,12 all need to be linked

Comment: Just have a unique id for each row.

Comment: Cannot do that, because each plan would then be completely unlinked. We need to know that plan:1 with frequency 1,6,12 are the same plan

Comment: That does not preclude having a unique identifier on each row.  You would still have the column that specifies the plan.

Comment: I put the primary key on (id, frequency) in fact and it works pretty good. But it looks like I need to have 2 columns in the website table so I will delete my question if nobody has an answer in a day to avoid bloating SO with unanswered questions :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon, I managed to work it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I hesitated between deleting my question or providing my answer as it could be too specific of a question. But just in case it helps others in the future, here it is:

It's so simple that I feel stupid for not doing this before, I just add another column "group" that will be auto_increment when creating a new independent plan, or will be set with the desired group to be related with the others. So I would just leave the primary key on only one column. so basically, instead of the plans table being like this:
id:1, frequency:1 (Plan 1, charged every month)
id:1, frequency:6 (Plan 1, charged every 6 months)
id:1, frequency:12 (Plan 1, charged every 12 months)
id:2, frequency:1 (Plan 2, charged every month)
...

It would be like this:
id:1, group:1, frequency:1 (Plan 1, charged every month)
id:2, group:1, frequency:6 (Plan 1, charged every 6 months)
id:3, group:1, frequency:12 (Plan 1, charged every 12 months)
id:4, group:2, frequency:1 (Plan 2, charged every month)
...

That way, the website table only needs one "plan_id" column to reference a plan, we can retrieve a plan by a single id, and we can retrieve all plans of the same group from an id.